# Is it problematic for SEO to noindex all pages linked in the navigation and have Google index separate canonical URLs instead?

Tags: seo, website-design, navigation

My website has `noindex`ed pages linked in navigation. The `noindex`ed pages have proper canonical tags to the indexed preferred pages.

Is it a good strategy? All normal URLs are indexed in search. How would it potentially harm the performance of the website?

Comment: Why would you set it up that way?

Comment: Because website is based on SharePoint cms which automatically generates ASPX pages which by default get deployed in the navigation.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want those pages indexed and create separate pages that get indexed?

Comment: No can't both versions of the pages are created by default. And indexing both would create duplication

Comment: Noindex does not mean nofollow. As far as I understand, the canonical link should be followed by Google and that page found. While in theory, the navigational links should all resolve and be your most important pages, I see how you have a dilemma. And while Google may find your canonical link and page, Google may not treat it as important without another signal (link). The further away a page is from the home page, the less important it becomes. For example, to confuse things, Google counts page rank within a sites ethos of links before applying it to the worlds ethos of links. Cheers!!

Comment: Google has always use a trust network model for page rank. For example, page A links to page B therefore trusts page B. Page B links to page C therefore trusts page C. In a trust network model, page A also trusts page C, however, because there is an extra hop between page A and page C, any trust between page A and page C is diminished. A fairly standard network trust calculation is made following links to establish PR. This is an overly simplified view of course, however, the same mechanism is applied to a site from the home page to all other pages. Clear as mud?

Comment: Thanks closetnoc! Would another signal be through internal linking the secondary and tertiary pages within body content with indexable URLs. Currently kind of trying this out.